# Offline spell checking api

Tags: android, nlp

I'm building my own custom IME and want to include spell checking. Are there any offline spell checking api's that are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API guide:

> The Android platform offers a spelling checker framework that lets you
> implement and access spell checking in your application. The framework
> is one of the Text Service APIs offered by the Android platform.

Source [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html).

You can also find a sample spelling checker app in your SDK sample folder.

Comment: Is that available before API Level 15? I want to use it for level 8 or 10

Comment: No, unfortunately it was added in API 14. However I found this here:http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/source/checkout, it might help you

Comment: That requires internet connection correct? Do you know of any services that are available offline?

Comment: No, sorry I don't know any other.

Answer (score 0):

Languagetool is Java a based spell checking and proofreading software that might fit.
See

- https://www.languagetool.org/
- http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languagetool

It's been successfully used with android. See userforum.